# error: cannot convert ‘std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}’ to ‘char**’ for getline() function

Tags: c++

I had this program working a while ago but I recently came back to look at it for another project I am working on and now I am getting errors while trying to use `getline()`

The other file is just a text file that has the player's name, their position and other data about them as such:

> Bill Quarter_Back 70 0 8754 0 573

before adding :: infront of the getline function I was getting the error

> error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::ifstream&, int&, char)’
>
> ```
> getline(input, p[i].position, ' '); "
> ```

and I don't know why.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

struct player{
  int position, touchDowns, catches, passingYards, recievingYards, rushingYards;
  std::string name;
};
using namespace std;

void printPlayer(player p[], ifstream &input);
void createArray(player p[], ifstream &input);

int main() {
    ifstream input;
    player p[10];
    int choice;
    while(choice != 99){
      cout << "Select one of the following options: " << "1: To print a player's data\n2: To print the entire data\n3: To update a player's touch downs\n4: To update a player's number of catches\n5: To update a player's passing yards\n6: To update a player's receiving yards\n7: To update a player's rushing yards\99: To quit the program" <<endl;
      cin >> choice;
      switch (choice){
        case 1:
        printPlayer(p, input);
        
      }
      if(choice == 99){
        break;
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
void createArray(player p[], ifstream &input){
  for(int i =0;i < 10; i++){
    getline(input, p[i].name, ' ');
    getline(input, p[i].position, ' ');
    getline(input, p[i].touchDowns, ' ');
    getline(input, p[i].catches, ' ');
    getline(input, p[i].passingYards, ' ');
    getline(input, p[i].recievingYards);
    getline(input, p[i].rushingYards);
  }
}
void printPlayer(player p[], ifstream &input){
  int wantedPlayer;
  string guyname;
  cout << "Enter players name: ";
  cin >> wantedPlayer;
  cout << endl;
  for(int i =0; i < 10; i++){
    guyname = p[i].name;
      cout << p[i].name << " " << p[i].position << " " << p[i].touchDowns << " " << p[i].catches << " " << p[i].passingYards << " " << p[i].recievingYards << " " << p[i].rushingYards << "\n" << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `getline(input, p[i].position, ' ');` to do? Now, read the documentation. Does it do that?

Answer (score 3):

Without the `using namespace std;` statement ([which you should not use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/)), your calls to `getline()` would not be calling C++’s [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), but C’s [`getline()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) from `<stdio.h>`:

```cpp
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

Which is why you were getting errors about converting `std::ifstream` to `char**`. To fix that error, make sure you use `getline()` from the `std` namespace, eg:

```cpp
void createArray(player p[], std::ifstream &input){
  for(int i =0;i < 10; i++){
    std::getline(input, p[i].name, ' ');
    ...
  }
}
```

However, `std::getline()` can’t read input into an `int`, only into a `std::string`. If you want to read a formatted integer from text input, you will have to convert the `std::string` using `std::stoi()` or equivalent, eg:

```cpp
void createArray(player p[], std::ifstream &input){
  std::string temp;
  for(int i =0;i < 10; i++){
    ...
    std::getline(input, temp, ' ');
    p[i].position = std::stoi(temp);
    ...
  }
}
```

Otherwise, use `operator>>` instead:

```cpp
void createArray(player p[], std::ifstream &input){
  for(int i =0;i < 10; i++){
    input >> p[i].name >> p[i].position >> ...;
    input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ‘\n’);
  }
}
```